# Replace text in xml node with some value

Tags: xml, xslt

lets suppose I have an xml like

```
<Fractions>
<Fraction>test 1/3 test aaa</Fraction>
<Fraction>1/2 test</Fraction>
</Fractions>
```

I want to replace `1/3 with &amp;frac13`, `1/2 with @amp;frac12` which is in the string using xsl but I am stuck. The fraction values are limited like

```
1/2, 1/3, 3/4, 1/4.
```

Comment: Are 1/3 and 1/2 the only fractions that are going to appear in your XML, or are you going have a much greater number of fractions?

Comment: There could be greater num of fractions

Comment: Is there going to be an upper limit on the size of the fractions though, or could you have fractions like 1/1000000?

Comment: This is a ["number to word"](http://symphony-cms.com/download/xslt-utilities/view/20486/) as an example (never tested, just immediate googling). You will need to expand this to a "fraction to word". I think I would not answer this even for a +50 bounty, may be a +500.

Comment: there are fractions only like 1/2, 1/4, 1/3 to be replaced

Comment: @Abdul Muqtadir: We really do need to know if there is an upper limit on the denominator. If you are only going to have single digits, then a simple look-up table will be enough. If you are going to have fractions like 1/1384 or 1/292002, for example, then the more complication solution highlighted by empo will be needed.

Comment: neither the denominator nor the numerator could be greater than one digit.

Comment: The question has changed quite a bit since it was answered (there is now extra text in the Input XML, and iot no longer requires numbers changed to words). It may be better to put the question back to how it was, and ask another question to avoid confusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that the input XML will only have single digits, you could achieve this with simple look-up tables, which return the name of either the cardinal number (one, two, three, etc) or the ordinal form of the number (Half, Third, Fourth, etc)

```
   <ref:cardinals>
      <ref:cardinal>One</ref:cardinal>
      <ref:cardinal>Two</ref:cardinal>
      <ref:cardinal>Three</ref:cardinal>
      ... and so on...
   </ref:cardinals>

   <ref:ordinals>
      <ref:ordinal>Half</ref:ordinal>
      <ref:ordinal>Third</ref:ordinal>
      ... and so on ...
   </ref:ordinals>
```

(Where the **ref** namespace would have to be declared at the top of the XSLT)

To look up values in these look-up tables, you could set up a variable which references the XSLT document itself

```
<xsl:variable name="cardinals" select="document('')/*/ref:cardinals"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$cardinals/ref:cardinal[position() = $numerator]"/>
```

(Where $numerator is a variable containing the top half of the fraction)

Here is a full XSLT document which can cope with all single digit fractions

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ref="http://stackoverflow.com/users/723763/abdul-muqtadir">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <ref:cardinals>
      <ref:cardinal>One</ref:cardinal>
      <ref:cardinal>Two</ref:cardinal>
      <ref:cardinal>Three</ref:cardinal>
      <ref:cardinal>Four</ref:cardinal>
      <ref:cardinal>Five</ref:cardinal>
      <ref:cardinal>Six</ref:cardinal>
      <ref:cardinal>Seven</ref:cardinal>
      <ref:cardinal>Eight</ref:cardinal>
      <ref:cardinal>Nine</ref:cardinal>
   </ref:cardinals>

   <ref:ordinals>
      <ref:ordinal>Half</ref:ordinal>
      <ref:ordinal>Third</ref:ordinal>
      <ref:ordinal>Quarter</ref:ordinal>
      <ref:ordinal>Fifth</ref:ordinal>
      <ref:ordinal>Sixth</ref:ordinal>
      <ref:ordinal>Seventh</ref:ordinal>
      <ref:ordinal>Eigth</ref:ordinal>
      <ref:ordinal>Ninth</ref:ordinal>
   </ref:ordinals>

   <xsl:variable name="cardinals" select="document('')/*/ref:cardinals"/>
   <xsl:variable name="ordinals" select="document('')/*/ref:ordinals"/>

   <xsl:template match="Fraction">
      <xsl:variable name="numerator" select="number(substring-before(., '/'))"/>
      <xsl:variable name="denominater" select="number(substring-after(., '/'))"/>
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:value-of select="$cardinals/ref:cardinal[position() = $numerator]"/>
         <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="$ordinals/ref:ordinal[position() = $denominater - 1]"/>
         <xsl:if test="$numerator != 1">s</xsl:if>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input XML, the following XML is returned

```
<Fractions>
   <Fraction>One Third</Fraction>
   <Fraction>One Half</Fraction>
</Fractions>
```

Note that you may have to look at handling plurals better. For example, if you had 3/2 as a fraction, the above solution returns Three Halfs, and not Three Halves.

Comment: I am really grateful to your answer. What if I want to replace 1/3 to '&amp;frac13;' 3/4 to '&amp;frac34;' and so and so.

Answer (score 0):

If there's only a few, then use templates like these:

```
<xsl:template match="Fraction/text()[.='1/2']">half</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Fraction/text()[.='1/3']">one-third</xsl:template>
etc..
```

Comment: The xsl is like <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"> <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/> <xsl:template match="Fraction/text()[.='1/2']">&amp;frac12;</xsl:template> <xsl:template match="Fraction/text()[.='1/3']">&amp;frac13;</xsl:template> </xsl:stylesheet> but its not replacing 1/2 or 1/3 if present in xml

Comment: Oh, the text is WITHIN other text? Sorry, by your example it looked like `1/2` or `1/3` was the entire content of the node. In that case you need a recursive text-replace template. There's probably numerous examples on SO.

Comment: If you could put a solution, that would be a great help.